# question about SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on a small project involving oracle database,
and I have the following tables:

```
CUSTOMER ( Cid, CName, City, Discount )
PRODUCT ( Pid, PName, City, Quantity, Price )
ORDERS ( OrderNo, Month, Cid, Aid, Pid, OrderedQuantity, Cost )
```

How can retrieve the names of all customers who ordered all the products?

For example if customer x ordered product1, product2 and product3 (which are all the products the company offers) he will be selected. And if customer y only ordered product 1 and 2 but not 3 he will not be selected.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you use plsql or only SQL?

Answer (score 5):

You want "relational division".

```
select *
  from customer c
 where not exists( -- There are no product
          select 'x'
            from product p
           where not exists(  -- the customer did not buy
                    select 'x'
                      from orders o
                     where o.cid = c.cid 
                       and o.pid = p.id));
```

or

```
select c.cid
      ,c.name
  from customer c
  join orders   o using(cid)
 group
    by c.id
      ,c.name
having count(distinct o.pid) = (select count(*) from product);
```

Here is a great article by Joe Celko that shows several ways of implementing relational division (and variations): [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: +1. If someone is interested on learning more about relational division, Joe Celko has written a pretty nice article about it here: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Comment: @Kaitsu, I couldn't find my SQL for smarties, so I googled celko and relation division. Just finished reading the article when I saw your comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` and use a `having` clause to demand that the customer has ordered all products there are:

```
select  c.CName
from    Customers c
join    Orders o
on      o.Cid = c.Cid
group by
        c.Cid
,       c.CName
having  count(distinct o.Pid) = (select count(*) from products)
```

IMHO more readable than the "relational divison" approach, but less efficient.