# Performing a deletion in 3 related tables

Tags: sql, oracle

| Table1 | Table2 | Table3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Req_id | Req_id | env_id=1 |
|  | env_id(FK) | env_id=2 |

Ignoring other fields...Each req_id in Table 2 has an env_id and it gets this env_id from Table 3.

If a req_id in Table 2 has a record with EVERY env_id in Table 3, I want to delete that req_id from Table 1.

Since the env_id's in Table 3 will be different in every environment where I will run this script. So, Delete script needs to be written dynamically.
Thank you for any help.

```
   BEGIN
       FOR a
          IN (SELECT ENV_ID FROM Table3 t3)
            LOOP
              BEGIN
               DELETE FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.ID IN
               (SELECT t1.ID FROM Table1 t1
                INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.REQ_ID = t1.REQ_ID
                INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t3.ENV_ID = t2.ENV_ID
                AND t2.ENV_ID=a.ENV_ID)
              END;
           END LOOP;
      COMMIT;
    END;
```

Comment: What's your question about this? Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Does this respond to your question ? https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Comment: I using Oracle.

Comment: Check out ON DELETE CASCADE foreign key.

Comment: nop i wanna delete records from table2.

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve this? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Title, message text, code you posted - all suggest that you want to delete a row from **table1**. Comment (you posted an hour ago) says that you want to delete rows from **table2**. What do you really want? Sample data would help. Also, as far as I understood the "model" you posted, you can't delete anything from table2 nor table1 as long as child rows exist in table3.

Comment: Sorry for typo, i have edited my post. If a record in table 2 has a record with ALL env_id in table 3, I want to delete the records in table 1 that they are related to table2.

Answer (score 0):

> If a req_id in Table 2 has a record with EVERY env_id in Table 3, I want to delete that req_id from Table 1.

I believe you're describing [relational division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) here. In sql, it's not so obvious how to write/read queries for this operation so there are a lot of questions/answers in stackoverflow and elsewhere.

Some examples:

- [question about SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531945/question-about-sql-query/5531978#5531978)
- [How to represent relational division(basic algebra expression) in terms of SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868224/how-to-represent-relational-divisionbasic-algebra-expression-in-terms-of-sql)
- [Select group of rows that match all items in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977126/select-group-of-rows-that-match-all-items-in-a-list/15977167#15977167) (sql server)

The rest of your requirements should just be joining through to the correct tables for the delete.